# Generate m3u8 segments on the fly using fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Essentially, I have a video file called `very-large-video.mkv` that's ~1GB. I want to generate a `.m3u8` file (used for HLS streaming), but use `fluent-ffmpeg` to generate the `.ts` files on the fly, so I don't have to store a copy of the video.

I've tried using `ffmpeg` to figure out the command needed to generate the segments, but can't find the right set of parameters.